# Should you show buttons in previews?

Tags: website-design, interactive-ui, preview

A user can create a form for the users to fill in by adding input fields etc. They want to be able to preview this form and see how the fields look like for the user. They have no control over the submit button and cancel button. Should those buttons still be visible in the preview even though those buttons do nothing or should they be hidden? Disabled?

Comment: I think they should be shown in Preview mode. The intention for the whole feature is for the 'super user' to get a perspective on what the end user will see ultimately. There is no real reason to hide those buttons IMO. Disabled ? may be .. but that is still 'in view', that should be fine, if you have to disable. In preview mode, buttons dont trigger any action anyway (?)

Comment: The argument we are having inside our team is that the buttons aren't modifiable by the user so they will always be the same. Some in our team argue for that you should only be able to preview things you can change because that is what is directly relevant for you. Adding buttons would confuse them.

You are correct that the buttons wouldn't trigger anything if they were clickable in preview mode.

Comment: Now reading your post again.. '.. you wrote "A user can create a form for the users..." is there a difference between the two 'users'.

Comment: Yes, it's more like "An admin can create a form which are used by students" or something similar.

Comment: Why would the buttons confuse the Admin in Preview mode ? Preview is meant for making sure the look and feel is as per expectation-design. I would keep Buttons. You really need to hear a strong reason from the other side, for not displaying buttons in Preview mode.

Comment: I agree with you but some in my team are making the case that having buttons that don't do anything is useless and don't add anything to the preview. Furthermore, some say use disabled buttons because if the buttons don't do anything then they shouldn't be clickable.

Comment: I'd rather the buttons exist in the exact location and format as the official page, but just send me a quick message when I click the action, telling me that this is only a preview.

Answer (score 1):

By all means, Preview means to show what user will see when they act on. It's like a final rehearsal before doing the actual action. If Preview is missing some elements, it misses the point. What if buttons don't look like user wanted? Or located not where they wanted? Or named not like they wanted? Yes, they have no means to change that, but giving them a hint of how the final form will look like is a good UX practice. And the buttons should not be grayed out or somehow else visually affected. We want the preview to be a carbon copy of actual form.

If you like to look at an example of a good preview, try Facebook ads. You will see your ad as other users will. There are all kinds of buttons, images etc, but none of them are clickable.